# TYPO3: disable cache for specific plugin / extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase

I built an extension and a plugin where frontend-users can edit their profile but I noticed a critical issue:

Under "Edit profile", users could see the full information about another user who wasn't even logged in. Apparently the form was a cached on the server because after adding:

```
config.no_cache = 1
```

it didn't happen again. Now the issue is that indexing is disable on the whole website.

Is there a way to disable caching only for this specific extension / plugin ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have something like this in your `ext_localconf.php` :

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
        $_EXTKEY,
        'List',
        array('User' => 'list,editProfil'),
        array('User' => 'editProfil') // Uncached actions
);
```

Here is where it is explained : https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/4-FirstExtension/7-configuring-the-plugin.html

Comment: The first array is not "cached actions" but "switchable controller actions". ***All*** of your actions have to be listed there. And uncached actions are additionally in the second array.

Comment: Correction, they are not "switchable controller actions" - this term has another, different meaning in Extbase. They are "all allowed actions per controller". The term switchable controller actions applies to an internal logic that is able to *change the default action and allowed action list of the plugin based on flexform or TypoScript settings* and these apply on top of the allowed actions list you define with the configurePlugin method (you can't enable an action with switchable controller actions if it isn't also allowed in this array).

Answer (score 7):

If you want this to only apply on specific pages or be controllable by integrators, you can override the TS rendering instruction for the object:

```
tt_content.list.20.YOURLISTTYPEHERE = USER_INT
```

Or if you registered it as a custom CType:

```
tt_content.YOURCTYPEHERE.20 = USER_INT
```

The above should work for fluid_styled_content and css_styled_content.

It is almost never advisable to use `config.no_cache = 1` since this disables a lot of things other than just caching, as you found out. It also disables all caching for the entire page and it is almost always better for performance to only make the specific plugin not cacheable - and if possible, only do so on pages where the plugin gets used to render views which should not be cached.

Be careful if you do end up needing to cache some parts of your view. It isn't a silver bullet in terms of security, but it is a good start to always include the user's ID (and possibly other things from the authentication as well) in any cache identifiers. And try not to store sensitive information in caches at any point, including code where you output things like the user's name.

Comment: This is the correct solution for the question named in the title.
Thank you Claus.

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57506026/415353) for disabling the cache for specific `fluid_styled_content` element.

Comment: Me too that helped. Thanks!