# TYPO3 - Howto disable cache for specific content element on a page?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, view-helpers

Is it possible to disable the caching for one specific element on pages? I tried already the following typoscript, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45506800), but it is not working for me (TYPO3 v8):

```
tt_content.textmedia.20 = USER_INT
```

I am using `ext:fluid_styled_content` with custom CTypes. From my understanding the above typoscript should disable the caching for the content element "Text & Media" (just as an example).

My custom element reads live data from an API using a ViewHelper. But the ViewHelper is just called, when the element is not cached. Othervise the cached content will be shown.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

fluid_styled_content uses the FLUIDTEMPLATE content object instead of USER as it was in css_styled_content. FLUIDTEMPLATE has no "non-cached" variant. I believe there are some options to change the caching of that element, but I could not find anything on that in the documentation.

Alternatively you could wrap it in a COA_INT object, which would look like something like this:

```
tmp.textmedia < tt_content.textmedia
tt_content.textmedia >
tt_content.textmedia = COA_INT
tt_content.textmedia {
    10 < tmp.textmedia
    10 =< lib.contentElement
}
```

If you take a look in the typoscript object browser (Template module), before the change it should look something like this:

[image]

And after the change it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: You are my personal hero, that works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Me too that helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

But this construction for `ext:form` **not works**

```
tmp.tt_content.form_formframework < tt_content.form_formframework
tt_content.form_formframework >
tt_content.form_formframework = COA_INT
tt_content.form_formframework {
    10 < tmp.tt_content.form_formframework
    10 =< lib.contentElement
}

tmp.tt_content.list.20.form_formframework < tt_content.list.20.form_formframework
tt_content.list.20.form_formframework >
tt_content.list.20.form_formframework = USER_INT
tt_content.list.20.form_formframework {
    10 < tt_content.list.20.form_formframework
    10 =< lib.contentElement
}
```

for `ext:news` **not works**

```
tmp.tt_content.list.20.news_pi1 < tt_content.list.20.news_pi1
tt_content.list.20.news_pi1 >
tt_content.list.20.news_pi1 = USER_INT
tt_content.list.20.news_pi1 {
    10 < tt_content.list.20.news_pi1
    10 =< lib.contentElement
}
```