# How does one make TYPO3 generate different output for backend users?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-11.x

I would like to output additional data in most content elements (mostly `fluid_styled_content`) in the frontend for logged-in backend users (editing links for the CEs, additional information). The first idea was to insert additional Fluid code within [`<f:be.security.ifAuthenticated>`](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Be/Security/IfAuthenticated.html). In theory this does the right thing, but the result is cached (bad: BE users might not see the additional data, others might see it). How does one work around this?

Ideas:

1. Use different templates for BE users. How?
2. Disable writing to and reading from the cache for BE users. How?
3. (Automatically) Assign a FE user group to BE users, because the cache should create different entries for each FE user group. How?
4. Render the additional output using JavaScript and get the data separately. Caching could work for all users, but complicated and would still require some way to discriminate between BE-/non-BE users. Would prefer not to implement this.

Requirements for a solution:

1. FE caching should continue to work for users which are not logged into the BE.
2. Caching for BE users does not necessarily have to work, but would be nice-to-have.
3. The output does not need to differ further between users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could deactivate the page cache for logged in backend users [with a TypoScript condition](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#backend-user-isloggedin):

```
[backend.user.isLoggedIn]
  config.no_cache = 1
[global]
```

That seems excessive and there should be better solutions.

Ideas:

- Add a cacheTag depending on BE login state (this would enable caching for all users)
- disable caching in your content element definition's TypoScript by wrapping the `FLUIDTEMPLATE` in a `COA_INT` (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57505896/typo3-howto-disable-cache-for-specific-content-element-on-a-page)) (this would only disable caching for that `FLUIDTEMPLATE`)
- Can [`<f:cache.disable>`](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3fluid/fluid/latest/Cache/Disable.html) around the condition help? I found these to have no effect in plain content elements (`FLUIDTEMPLATE`), though.
- Can [`<vhs:render.uncache>`](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/blob/development/Classes/ViewHelpers/Render/UncacheViewHelper.php) help?

Comment: I disabled the page cache as suggested (config.no_cache=1); wonder if additional caches (pagesection, fluid_template) might interfere. Regarding the other ideas:  Unsure how to add cache tags, would probably invalidate pages always. What'd really be needed are varying cache identifiers; don't see hooks for that. Disabling caching in most CEs would be too much. f:cache.disable only disables compilation of the template to PHP, but the result would be cached still from what I understand. vhs:render.uncache looks interesting, unsure about performance impact; need to check its implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is called "frontend editing" - it is available as an extension that can be found here: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/frontend_editing

Comment: That'd be nice, too, but I feel it's got somewhat little attention and would require more work to set up in this case. In general a decent suggestion, though.